# Run .BAT file with Minimal Keystrokes

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have a .BAT file on Windows that takes a screenshot and automatically uploads it unto a webpage. So, i am trying to find a way to run this file with as little keystrokes possible, preferably up to 3 only (eg. Ctrl + Alt + X). The purpose of this is so that i can simply hit the relevant keystrokes every time there's something on my screen that i would like to take a screenshot of and share on my website!

Thanks in advance :)

Code Sample of my .BAT file:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\Screenshot Uploader (Windows)
screenshot.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
CD %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Screenshots
RENAME "Screenshot (*).png" Screenshot_(*).png
FOR /f %%I in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') DO SET recent=%%I
FOR /f "TOKENS=2-4 DELIMS=/ " %%A in ('date /t') DO SET cdate=%%A-%%B-%%C
FOR /f "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/:." %%X in ("%TIME%") DO SET ctime=%%X%%Y%%Z
SET /a ctime=%ctime%-3
RENAME %recent% %cdate%_%ctime%.png
CD %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\Screenshot Uploader (Windows)
curl -u username:password -if -F "f=@%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Screenshots\%cdate%_%ctime%.png" https://example.com/upload.php -k
EXIT
```

Comment: you can get curl for windows

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: He's asking how to make a screenshot of a focused window & upload it in one step.